# How to take a complex matrix based input from the user and pass it onto a vbs function?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to automate a page, where different forms gets displayed to different user (based on credentials), and different input fields get displayed for which input is seeked from the end-user.

Here is an example :

```
User | Forms accessible | Fields accessible
User 1 >  Form 1 > Name
                 > Address
                 > Occupation

User 2 > Form 2  > Safety code
                 > Access auth. code
       > Form 3  > Auditor acesss
                 > Auditee access 

User x > Form n  > Field 1.....n
```

My Approach so far:

I have tried  the dictionary approach someting like

```
dictionary("Users") = "User1~User2~User3"
dictionary("Form") = "Form1#Form2~Form3#FormN"  '<<"#" is the seperator for users
dictionary("Fields") = "field1$field2#field3$field4~field5#Field6"
```

Here is the mapping explained:

- User1 → Form 1 → Field1 and field2
- User 2 → form 2 → field3
- User 2 → Form 3 → field4 and field 5
- User 3 → Form N → Field 1...N

And then based on these separator and inputs i filter them out and make appropriate operations.

I am SURE that this is NOT an elegant solution. Would really appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

One proposed solution is to maintain an external XML file which maintains access matrix for users AND forms AND Fields, and then pass that XML to the current function.

Comment: Hi. You mentioned 'make a page' - is this therefore related to generating HTML or are you talking about some kind of form? The answers will differ depending on the technology and the overall goal. So - please edit the question and describe the technology in use and the display mechanism.

Comment: Why do you encode your data in a dictionary with 3 different strings instead of one dictionary-based data structure?